# Most programing languages have 'include library into your code' function but where is function 'include your code into library'?

Tags: dll

Most programing languages have 'include library into your code' function but where is function 'include your code into library'?

I Mean push into other files from the source, rather than pull into from the consuming files.

Idea is simple - we have a library `A` with class `B` we want to extend `B` with some `C` functions but we do not want to do it by extending from `B`, but by extending `B`.

So if we had library like DLL with functions and we would like to add functions to that DLL with out crating new DLL, and keeping ability to call that new functions as if we were calling  that first DLL.

Point is not in having DLL sources and modifying tham, and not in wrapping around all functions in that dll just for adding few new functions creating new dll, but in adding functionality into existing dll and getting that modified DLL back. With no wrapping around but with inserting inside.

If you find this question a QUESTION, please vote for reopening.

If you have something to add - please add - it's comunity wiki.

Comment: Can you explain in more detain what you are asking about?

Comment: what do you mean by 'include into' ?

Comment: He means push into other files from the source, rather than pull into from the consuming files. Clear to me.

Comment: Where was that stooped and mealy-colored old man I used to call poppa when the merry-go-round broke down?

Comment: Maybe it is trapped in a Martin Fowler paper?

Comment: @David M: I'm trying very hard to figure out what purpose this feature would have. I imagine it would let you tell the compiler that any file named "B" extant now or in the futue must include "A", but I can't imagine why I would want to do this (can you? if so, please enlighten me!). Seems like it would create more problems than it would solve.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Idea is simple - we have a library A with class B we want to extend B with some C functions but we do not want to do it by extending from B, but by extending B

Comment: Not off the top of my head, no. But that doesn't mean it's not a real question...

Comment: @Ole Jak: So you want to modify the definition of B? I think some languages let you re-open the definitions of classes. I think Ruby can do this: http://practicalruby.blogspot.com/2007/02/reopen-with-moduleeval.html Not sure if this is the same as what you meant though, and I don't think it's the same as "include into" because it's still the future-written classes that are re-opening the class. Also, I'm not fluent enough in Ruby to know how often this feature is actually used, or if it's even safe. Seems like it could have unexpected side-effects on code that depends on the pre-reopened class

Comment: @Adam Crossland: edited Question, does it seem more clear now what do I mean?

Comment: @Ole, what you describe is not a particularly simple idea. Or a very good one, I think. Modifying the contract of a module from outside of the module introduces a world of hurtful problems and potential for disaster. The wisest way to add capabilities is to have a new class inherit from it.

Comment: @Adam: at least vote for reopening question...

Comment: You seem to be confusing compiler includes and compiled libraries.  You can add more functionality to a DLL if you've got the source and compiler without doing confusing things with source code.  Adding new functions to an existing DLL without having the source code is a much larger problem.  In other words, what you've got there is an incoherent question, hence not a real question.

Comment: @ David Thornley: yes, adding new functions to an existing DLL without having the source code is a much larger problem. And I would love to see a solution for my problem.)

Comment: @Ole Jak: Could you create a new DLL that wraps the old DLL and includes new functionality?

Comment: Hmm! A suddenly flurry of downvotes on old questions of mine! Very nice.

Comment: @Adam Crossland: offtop... sorry for u

Comment: @Ole Jak: With your newest update, I don't think what you want is *easily* possible. It sounds like you want to inject new functionality into an existing compiled DLL. It's probably possible, I think some viruses do that as a way to spread. I don't think any language/environment explicitly offers this capability as an inherent feature, but hacking it in should be possible.

Comment: @Ole Jak:  This isn't a programming language issue.  Language specs don't generally deal with the makeup of DLLs; they just say what the code will do.  I'm going to edit the tags.  That being said, you've now got a reasonable question, so I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Why is this question CW? Just because it's a bad question doesn't mean it should be CW.

Comment: @Ole Jak: what languages are you talking about that have the functionality to include a library into your code? Most programming languages don't know anything about libraries at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends a lot on the programming language at hand.

In C++, any module (because there are no modules) can add content to any namespace. You can link two different DLL's both adding members to the same namespace.

C# takes it a step further, not only can anyone add to any namespace, but you can use "extension methods" to add methods to existing classes.

In Ruby, reopening classes is simply done by defining part of the class elsewhere, effectively having multiple definitions of a class. But they all refer to the same class, so at runtime, they all end up in the same one.

In Lua you can reopen modules with the "module" function and add anything you want.

None of this actually modifies the "source" of the original code - but they offer natural, seamless extensions to it, so it's probably as close as you get.